Store outputs of every loop into a list
I would like to store outputs of every look into a list. I have a task like this:
- name: Get ping data
  set_fact:
    packets_received: "{{ item | regex_search('(\\d*) packets received', '\\1'))[0] }}"
    packet_loss: "{{ item | regex_search('(\\d*)% packet loss', '\\1'))[0] }}"
    latency: "{{ item | regex_search('(\\d*\\.\\d*)\\/(\\d*\\.\\d*)\\/(\\d*\\.\\d*) ms', '\\1', '\\2', '\\3')) }}"

  loop: 
    "{{ping_output['results']}}"

I want to store these 3 variables into a new list like [ {packets_received: value, packet_loss: value, latency: value}, {packets_received: value, packet_loss: value, latency: value} ]
I have trouble doing this as using combine filter just replaces the items in the list as it has the same key name.

Would using a Custom Module like icmp_ping.py be a solution for you?

@U880D No, I would like to use ansible playbook entirely. I just need to loop through an existing list, that is, ping_output['results'] in this case, and then insert the results of packets_received, packet_loss & latency into a new empty list. I have the pinging part working fine.

Because "Ansible is not recommended as a data processing/manipulation tool" and from "Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials: Think declaratively: Ansible is a Desired State Engine by design. If you’re trying to "write code" in your plays and roles, you’re setting yourself up for failure. Our YAML-based playbooks were never meant to be for programming.", are there any hard requirements why do you like to write it within the playbook itself? See also https://www.ansible.com/blog/the-zen-of-ansible/

For example, let's collect the ping results from three hosts
  rhosts: [test_11, test_12, test_13]

    - command: ping -c 3 {{ item }}
      register: ping_output
      loop: "{{ rhosts }}"

Install jc on the controller and parse the output by the filter community.general.jc
  pings:  "{{ ping_output.results |
              map(attribute='stdout') |
              map('community.general.jc', 'ping') }}"

gives (abridged)
 pings:
    -   data_bytes: 56
        destination: test_11
        destination_ip: 10.1.0.61
        duplicates: 0
        packet_loss_percent: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
        packets_transmitted: 3
        pattern: null
        responses:
        -   bytes: 64
            duplicate: false
            icmp_seq: 1
            response_ip: 10.1.0.61
            time_ms: 2.56
            timestamp: null
            ttl: 64
            type: reply
        -   bytes: 64
            ...

In most cases, this would be all you need. You can use the list in declarations or directly to iterate the results. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          packets_received: {{ item.packets_received }}
          packet_loss: {{ item.packet_loss_percent }}
          latency: {{ item.time_ms }}
      loop: "{{ pings }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.destination_ip }}"

gives
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.1.0.61) => 
  msg: 'packets_received: 3 packet_loss: 0.0 latency: 2003.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.1.0.62) => 
  msg: 'packets_received: 3 packet_loss: 0.0 latency: 2001.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.1.0.63) => 
  msg: 'packets_received: 3 packet_loss: 0.0 latency: 2001.0'

If you want to select some keys there are more options:

The most simple one is community.general.keep_keys. Declare the target

  target: [packets_received, packet_loss_percent, time_ms]

and select the keys
  result: "{{ pings | community.general.keep_keys(target=target) }}"

gives
  result:
    -   packet_loss_percent: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
        time_ms: 2003.0
    -   packet_loss_percent: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
        time_ms: 2001.0
    -   packet_loss_percent: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
        time_ms: 2001.0


If you have to use your keys

  target: [packets_received, packet_loss, latency]

use community.general.json_query and community.general.dict
  result: "{{ pings |
              json_query('[].[packets_received, packet_loss_percent, time_ms]') |
              map('zip', target) |
              map('map', 'reverse') |
              map('community.general.dict') }}"

gives what you want
  result:
    -   latency: 2003.0
        packet_loss: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
    -   latency: 2001.0
        packet_loss: 0.0
        packets_received: 3
    -   latency: 2001.0
        packet_loss: 0.0
        packets_received: 3



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    rhosts: [test_11, test_12, test_13]
    pings:  "{{ ping_output.results |
                map(attribute='stdout') |
                map('community.general.jc', 'ping') }}"

    target: [packets_received, packet_loss_percent, time_ms]
    result: "{{ pings | community.general.keep_keys(target=target) }}"

    targe2: [packets_received, packet_loss, latency]
    resul2: "{{ pings |
                json_query('[].[packets_received, packet_loss_percent, time_ms]') |
                map('zip', targe2) |
                map('map', 'reverse') |
                map('community.general.dict') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: ping -c 3 {{ item }}
      register: ping_output
      loop: "{{ rhosts }}"

    - debug:
        var: pings | to_nice_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: >-
          packets_received: {{ item.packets_received }}
          packet_loss: {{ item.packet_loss_percent }}
          latency: {{ item.time_ms }}
      loop: "{{ pings }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.destination_ip }}"

    - debug:
        var: result | to_nice_yaml

    - debug:
        var: resul2 | to_nice_yaml



Good point. Using Community General Collection Filters is probably simpler than operating and maintaining an own Custom Module ... +1

Yes. jc and json_query is a must-have.
